# Pointer Objects comparison using pointer expression in cpp

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

I create a two pointer object of a class '**myclass**'

```
myclass *obj1,*obj2;
```

can I compare these two objects using comparison operator and pointer expression i.e `*obj1==*obj2`

**If yes, how does it happen?**
**If not, why isn't his allowed?**

Comment: Are your two pointers pointing to valid objects, or are they uninitialized?  If the latter, then you are going to invoke undefined behavior when you try to dereference them with the * operator (and most likely your program will crash)

Comment: C++ is not C and "cpp' is not a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If yes, how does it happen? 
>   If not, why isn't his allowed?

In short the answer will be **yes** if you have defined a suitable `operator ==` function for comparing `myclass` instances and **no** if you have not defined a suitable `operator ==` function.

There are two ways to declare an `operator ==` function - as a member function of the `MyClass` class or as a non-member function (sometimes called a global function or free function).

Declaring a `MyClass` member function might look something like this...

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    bool operator == (const MyClass &rhs) const
    {
        bool result{ false };

        // calculate result;

        return result;
    }

    // ... etc ...
};
```

Given the statement `if (*obj1 == *obj2)` the member function above would be called on the `*obj1` instance (i.e., `this` would refer to `*obj1`) while the `*obj2` instance would be passed as the argument to the parameter `rhs`.

Alternatively, the equality comparison operator for `MyClass` could be declared as a non-member (aka global) function...

```
bool operator == (const MyClass &lhs, const MyClass &rhs) 
{
    bool result{ false };

    // calculate result;

    return result;
}
```

In this case, given the statement `if (*obj1 == *obj2)` the function above would be called  with the `*obj1` instance passed as the argument to the `lhs` parameter and the `*obj2` instance passed as the argument to the `rhs` parameter.

You cannot declare both a member function and a non-member function `operator ==` using the same signature.  The compiler wouldn't be able to decide which one to call!

Whichever technique you use to declare an `operator ==` function, the "calculate result" code can be absolutely anything that makes sense for your particular class, so long as it returns `true` or `false`.

Typically you would compare the various members of the two objects and return true if those members held the same values.  But you might not compare **all** members.  Consider, for example, the following `Book` class...

```
class Book
{
public:

   std::string Title;
   std::string Author;
   std::string Isbn;

   // ... etc ...
};
```

You might decide that `operator ==` should return true only if the two instances have equal ISBN values because different editions of a book like *The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy* should be considered different.  Alternatively you might decide that two `Book` instances are equal if they have the same `Title` and `Author` because paperback and hardback editions of the Guide might have different ISBNs but they're still (in some sense) the same book.

Finally(!) it should be noted that while the sample code above uses `const MyClass &` as the type for the `rhs` parameter C++ does not require that the `rhs` parameter be the same type as the `lhs` parameter.

Normally it would be of course, and defining an `operator ==` function that compared two dissimilar types would be likely to confuse readers and could cause problems for programmers using your class.  But, as is often the case, if you think you know what you are doing, C++ won't get in your way.

If you'd like to read more about comparison operators you might find http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> can I compare these two objects using comparison operator and pointer expression i.e `*obj1==*obj2`

Synactically speaking, you can do that only if the operator is defined for the class. You can do that by overloading the `operator==` function, which can be a member function or a non-member function.

It will work at run time only if `obj1` and `obj2` point to valid objects.

If `obj1` and `obj2` point to valid objects, `*obj1 == *obj2` will work just like if you had

```
MyClass o1;
MyClass o2;
```

and used `o1 == o2`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work, but only if you've overloaded the `==` operator for your class. If you have, then `==` will invoke the appropriate `operator==` method, which implements the equality test for your class. In other words, it's up to you to define what equality means for your class.

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator on pointers will compare their numeric address and hence determine if `*obj1` and *`obj2` points to the same object or not.

```
bool operator==(const myclass &obj2); // in this method, see if obj2 is equal to *this.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are suggesting will work only if myclass defines operator==.

And as Jeremy Friesner pointed out, you need to beware of invalid pointers, in particular the value NULL (or nullptr).

So what you really want is:
if ((obj1 != nullptr) && (obj2 != nullptr( && (*obj1 == *obj2)) ...

I would also recommend changing those identifiers to ptr1 and ptr2, as "obj1" and "obj2" would imply to the average reader that they are objects rather than pointers to objects. Or myclsptr1 and myclsptr2, as an indication to the reader of what sort of thing they point to. Or, better yet, names that indicate what their purpose is in this part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

1.Pointer to a class is similar-to pointer to a Structure where if you want to compare you have to access and compare each and every member.

2.You can compare **obj1==obj2**(which compares address) but if you want to compare two objects ***obj1==*obj2** you have to overload "==" operator in your "**myclass**" like this:::

`bool operator==(const myclass& b) {//Compare methods or variables of both objects and return result bool(true/false)`